# Убрать повторяющийся тег

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как можно скриптом убрать тег `<br>`, если подряд идут два?

Например:

```
текст
<br> (нужно убрать)
<br>
текст
<br>
текст
```

Comment: речь идет только о br тегах, или о любых? И вопрос туда же, повторяющиесь теги только открывающие или еще закрывающие ?

Comment: А что мешает убрать руками?

Comment: @Valentyn Anzhurov только открывающие br

Comment: @Pantera руками не вариант, долго объяснять

Comment: replace'ом земените два <br> на один

Answer (score 4):

Если теги написаны среди других тегов (т .е. между ними не голый текст), то оставить не более одного тега `br` подряд можно легко:

```
$("br + br").remove()
```

Если теги расставлены только внутри текста (нет других тегов), то так:

```js
$("br + br").filter(function () {
  for (var p=this; (p=p.previousSibling).nodeType === 3; ) {
    if ($(this.previousSibling).text().trim()) {
      return false
    }
  }
  
  return true
}).remove()
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

текст
<br>
<br>
текст
<br>
текст
```

Comment: ) "Пусть это будет просто: просто, как только можно, но не проще." *Альберт Эйнштейн

Comment: Хм.. А вообще неправильно ведь.

Comment: Это не сработает так, как нужно Чайник. Ему нужно убрать один из двух повторяющихся <br>

Comment: @Ghostik2005, во-первых, я уже сам написал, что не сработает. Во-вторых, на данный момент ни в одном из ответов полностью работающего кода нет.

Comment: @Ghostik2005, я исправил.

Comment: @Qwertiy да, вроде должно заработать как нужно автору. +1

Answer (score 0):

```js
let elems = document.querySelectorAll('br');

for(let i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  let elem = elems[i];
  
  if(elem.nextElementSibling.tagName === 'BR') {
     elem.remove();
     i++;
  }
}
```

```html
текст 0
<br>
<br>
<br>
текст 1
<br>
текст 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s.replace(/(<br>\s*){2,}\s*/, '<br>')
```

Comment: 1. И каким боком к вопросу регулярки? 2. Тем более, сомнительные регулярки.

Comment: @Qwertiy  а с чего нельзя использовать регулярки и чем она сомнительна ?

Comment: @Qwertiy если нужно редактировать дом, то вы правы, не подумал, что нужно редачить именно дом. Но для текста мой вариант подходит